# How to find out if there are files in a folder and exit accordingly (in KSH)

Tags: linux, ksh

I have a KSH (***not Bash***) script that I want to preempt with a file count check.  If there's no files I want to print "EMPTY" then exit. Otherwise proceed.

The problem is when I perform the file count, and it is EMPTY, then it breaks.

Code:

```
###################################################
# Test to see if files exist in Drop Folder
###################################################
CONTENTS=$(ls ${gp_path}ALLSTUFF*.zip)
if [[ ${#CONTENTS[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    print 'EMPTY'
    exit 0
else
    print 'NOT EMPTY'
fi
```

If not empty, it works.

If empty, I get the below error then the system breaks. I would like to have it just report EMPTY and exit 0:

Error:

```
/nas/Opt/databox/folder/ALLSTUFF*.zip not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Attempt #2

I tried this as well, but I got the same result:

```
if [ "$(ls ${gp_path}ALLSTUFF*.zip)" ]; then
    print 'NOT EMPTY'
else
    print 'EMPTY'
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Is that the whole error message you get? I would have expected `ls: cannot access '/nas/Opt/databox/folder/ALLSTUFF*.zip': No such file or directory`.  This is what `ls` would output on Linux when it can't find the files you specify on the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the error message disappear with `2>/dev/null` inside the `ls`.

You can then check to see if `$CONTENTS` is empty with `-z`

```
CONTENTS=$(ls -d -- "${gp_path}ALLSTUFF"*.zip 2>/dev/null)
if [ -z "$CONTENTS" ]; then
    print 'EMPTY'
    exit 0
else
    print 'NOT EMPTY'
fi
```

Comment: that worked.  Always forget that part.  as far as the `-z` goes, I can't be certain there are not other files in the folder.  I'm only looking for this one.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll give you the credit, when timer is good.

Comment: Note that it won't work properly if there are so many  files in there that executing `ls` fails with _too many arguments_

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on Stéphane Chazelas's comment to Kusalananda's answer:

```
$ ksh
$ echo ${.sh.version}
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ ls
TABLE1.csv  TABLE2.csv
```

Use an array to hold the files. Start with a glob expression that matches some files:

```
$ typeset -a files
$ files=( ~(N)*.csv )
$ echo "${#files[@]}"
2
$ typeset -p files
typeset -a files=(TABLE1.csv TABLE2.csv)
```

Now a "bare" glob that does not match to demonstrate that a non-matching glob is replaced by the glob pattern as a string:

```
$ files=( *.txt )
$ echo "${#files[@]}"
1
$ typeset -p files
typeset -a files=('*.txt')
```

Now with the "null glob" prefix

```
$ files=( ~(N)*.txt )
$ echo "${#files[@]}"
0
$ typeset -p files
(empty output)
$
```

See the File Name Generation section of your ksh man page.

---

To reply specifically to your question:

```
typeset -a contents=( ~(N)"$gp_path"/ALLSTUFF*.zip )
if [[ ${#contents[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    print 'EMPTY'
    exit 0
else
    print 'NOT EMPTY'
fi
```

You should get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names.

See also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Thank you so much, and this is helpful, but Stephen came first. +1 tho.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To detect whether a filename pattern expands to anything, you may use

```
set -- "$gp_path"ALLSTUFF*.zip

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo matched something
else
    echo did not match anything
    exit 1
fi
```

The `set` command sets the positional parameters to the filenames matched by the pattern, and if the first matched filename exists, then it matched something. The pattern remains unexpanded if it didn't match anything.

This would be usable in `ksh`, `bash` and any other `sh`-like shell.

Comment: In `ksh93`, use `~(N)` (reminiscent of `zsh`'s `(N)` glob qualifier) for a glob not to expand to anything when it doesn't match (much better than setting `nullglob` globally).

Comment: Thank you so much, and this is helpful, but Stephen came first. +1 tho.  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 Accepting the first answer just because it's the first answer does not makes sense.

Comment: @Kasulananda...I recognize that, but his was the first answer that worked.  That's why I gave him the check.